# Powerpoint VSTO TextRange.Find() only finds one result in Shape

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

Currently using the PowerPoint VSTO API to search for words within a PowerPoint presentation.

Bumped into an issue when searching a `TextRange` within a shape for a string with the expectation of more than one result to return.

The text I am doing the find on is (I have bolded the words to bring attention to them, they are not like this in the original):

> This is some text
>
> - Colour **vs** color
> - Some filler text
> - Some other filler text
> - Formalize **vs** formalise

```cs
var shape = presentation.Slides[1].Shapes[2];

var findResults = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Find("vs", 0, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse); 

var count = findResults.Count; //Expected 2, but only found 1
```

Any thoughts? I was expecting two results but at the moment I am only getting one, the first range "Colour vs color".

**Edit: Solution**
*Putting this here in case someone else comes across this (or I forget).*

Did some more digging and I discovered the `int after` argument in the `Find()` VSTO API. Essentially the `after` argument moves the range to search area on a number of characters you pass it. So passing in the end range of the first result and calling the `.Find()` again returns the next instance I was looking for.

For example:

```cs
var shape = presentation.Slides[1].Shapes[2];

var findResults1 = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Find("vs", 0, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse); 
//Returns the first vs instance "Colour vs color"

var findResults2 = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Find("vs", (findResults.Start + findResults.Length), MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse); 
//Returns the second vs instance "Formalize vs formalise"
```